# What's the .NET Core equivalent of Prefer32Bit?

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0, 32bit-64bit

Trying to use the old

```
<Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
```

option produces warning NETSDK1189: "Prefer32Bit is not supported and has no effect for netcoreapp target." It [has been said](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/64255#issuecomment-1021340266) that the prefer-32-bit option doesn't work because "the bitness of the process is not determined by this, it's determined by the host which is used to launch the app. If it's dotnet.exe, then it's up to the caller to pick the right one." But then, how does one tell dotnet.exe to prefer 32-bit, **without** forcing 32-bit (or a particular ISA) with `<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>`?

Comment: There are *two* versions of dotnet.exe, one in c:\program files and another in c:\program files (x86).  You'd prefer the latter.